# copy files to specified dir with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I want to copy somefile.bmp to my "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/data" folder but it doesn´t work. However if I change the path to "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin" it works fine. How can I fix this?

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Invaders POST_BUILD 
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
           "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/data/somefile.bmp"              
           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory does not exist, I guess. You need to create it before copying:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Invaders POST_BUILD 
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
           "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/data"
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
           "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/data/somefile.bmp"              
           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/data")
```